# Accessing SSAS using External User Database

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis, ssas

We have a BI team that have created a wonderful data warehouse that works fine for the internal staff using it through Excel on the internal network.  They use windows authentication through the domain controller, and everything works fine, including restricting the access to users and AD Groups.

The issue is that we now want to provide the same access to a wider audience that is not part of our Windows Domain.  This is further complicated by the fact that the information on the users that need access to the system is already stored in another location (an application with a SQL database).

The goal is to make it so that they connect (probably using HTTPS) to the cube (using Excel Analysis services integration), and be authenticated using the Username/Password that they had in the main application.

The main application has a WCF Service interface for user authentication, and session management, so all I really need is a way to provide authentication in front of the MSMDpump.dll against that WebService.  We can also add in a Role Mapping so that we can define the SSAS roles against the users in the application.

I was thinking that I could create a dll that has the same interface as the MSMDPUMP.dll, and have that translate calls between the client and the main dll, but this seems a bit of overkill.

Are there any pre-built tools to do this? (and yes I know that Sharepoint can do something like this, but that's not an option so please don't suggest it).  Does anybody know of any blogs detailing how to do it?

Any pointers in where to start with creating an interface between the 2?

The question is similar to [How to secure MS SSAS 2005 for HTTP remote access via Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126350/how-to-secure-ms-ssas-2005-for-http-remote-access-via-internet) however, I'm looking at providing the authentication mechanism from another datasource, and providing the Roles to SSAS, not the users.  We don't want to have to setup a new user in SSAS for every user that is setup in the external application.

UPDATE: To be clear, they external users need to connect to the cube using Excel, and the data returned needs to be filtered by the role they're in and the security applied in the Cube.
We are able to cahnge the cube to use Dynamic Dimension Security and use CustomData attributes if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventual solution ended up being a combination of a Third Party Control and Dynamic Dimension Security.

We found that it's not possible to easily apply a MembershipProvider interface to the MSMDPUMP interface without significant effort, so our solution gave them a Web Interface to use instead.

The Control we used was by DevExpress and is their "PivotGrid" control.  It's not free, but is significantly less than the development resource costs of implementing any other custom solution.

Along with the control, we've applied Dynamic Dimension Security to the Cube so each user of the Site will have a dedicated connectionString to the cube with "CustomData" appended to the connectionstring.  This allows us to delegate Data Segregation tasks to the Cube and BI team, and let the Web Developers concentrate on the display of the controls.

The solution is working quite well, and doesn't involve heavy weight applications like Sharepoint/Excel Services.  It can built directly into your site and branded as you need, providing a sales tool as well as a useful functional tool.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a limited-access user on the cube db (read-only, only for the relevant cube, etc.) and hard-code that user/password into a connection string on the app db?

Comment: How would I go about passing the individual users/roles through to SSAS?  In relation to the part "providing the Roles to SSAS, not the users", if I'm using a single user, the access will not be able to be defined in SSAS for the external users.

Comment: Do the users need access to individual information, like only the data pertaining to their client ID, or can anyone who's in the application see everything in the cube?

Comment: My thought is rather than setting up credentials for both Bob and Sally, set up one AD user for "CubeUser" and use that to authenticate to SSAS. The application would authenticate them using their existing logins and it would pull the relevant data from the cube with the CubeUser login. This only works if you have control over the application, though.

Comment: The target application for consuming the cube data is Excel, apologies as I thought I mentioned this in the question (kinda important really).  Therefore, they need to asked for credentials at the point of connection msmdpump (or the application layer above this).  however, I need some way of getting the User data (roles/userid/whatever) to SSAS so that security can be performed on the data that's returned.  Hope that makes it clearer.